# Cómo recuperar los datos de una consulta mysql

Tags: java, mysql

quisiera que alguien me explique como podría o como deberia hacer esta consulta a mi base de datos `SELECT c.campo1, p.campo2 FROM  tabla1 c, tabla2 p WHERE c.campo = p.campo`

actualmente estoy usando un metodo como el siguiente:

```
public ArrayList<Producto> Consultar() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    ArrayList<Producto> listaProductos = new ArrayList<Producto>();
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/empresa", "root", "ticowrc2017");
        String Sentencia = "SELECT Codigo, Ubicacion FROM producto";
        ps = con.prepareStatement(Sentencia);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            String codigo = producto.getCodigo(1);
            String ubicacion = producto.getUbicacion(2);
            Producto prod = new Producto(codigo, ubicacion);
            listaProductos.add(prod);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DATMaterial.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            rs.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DATMaterial.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    return listaProductos;
}
```

Comment: y cual es el problema? si reemplazas el query pasa algo malo?

Comment: perdón puse mal una parte del código y el problema es que en producto guardo el id de ubicación, mas no el nombre de la ubicación y lo que quiero es recuperar es (valga la redundancia) el nombre de la ubicacion

Comment: usa el boton [edit], pon la informacion correcta y hace la pregunta correcta. o sea tu problema no tiene nada que ver con Java si no que es que no sabes hacer el query?

Answer (score 3):

Roberth, en tu código hay varias cosas que necesitan ser mejoradas.

Veamos:

### 1. En este caso es mejor usar `Statement` y no `PreparedStatement`

En JDBC existen tanto `Statement` como `PreparedStatement`. El primero se usa generalmente en consultas que no manejan datos provenientes de otras fuentes (como entradas del usuario en un formulario que son usadas como criterios en la consulta). El segundo se usa cuando en la consulta intervienen datos externos, para proteger la consulta de la Inyección SQL. Tiene otras ventajas que no menciono aquí para no desviarme demasiado de tu problema. Para más detalles puedes [leer aquí](https://www.journaldev.com/2489/jdbc-statement-vs-preparedstatement-sql-injection-example).

Como tu consulta: `SELECT Codigo, Ubicacion FROM producto` está **blindada**, o sea, no interviene nada desde el exterior en ella, es mejor que uses `Statement`.

### 2. Error de comprensión en el uso de `ResultSet`.

Intentar leer los resultados así: `String codigo = producto.getCodigo(1);` es incorrecto.

De acuerdo a la documentación:

> #### Recuperar valores de columnas en las filas
>
> La interfaz `ResultSet` declara métodos getter (por ejemplo, `getBoolean` y `getLong`) para recuperar valores de columna de la fila actual. Puede recuperar
>   valores utilizando el número de índice de la columna o el alias o el
>   nombre de la columna. El índice de columna suele ser más eficiente.
>   Las columnas se numeran a partir de 1. Para una portabilidad máxima,
>   las columnas del conjunto de resultados dentro de cada fila se deben
>   leer en orden de izquierda a derecha, y cada columna debe leerse solo
>   una vez.
>
> [<sub>`ResultSet`en la documentación de Java</sub>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html)

En pocas palabras, para leer los datos no haces referencia a la tabla `producto`, sino al objeto `ResultSet` que apunta a los resultados, usando uno de sus `getter`, según el tipo de dato que esperes. Algo así: `String codigo = rs.getString(1);`.

### 3. Solución propuesta

Visto esto, propongo la siguiente solución:

```
public ArrayList<Producto> Consultar() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    ArrayList<Producto> listaProductos = new ArrayList<Producto>();

    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/empresa", "root", "ticowrc2017");
        String sentencia = "SELECT Codigo, Ubicacion FROM producto";
        Statement stmt = null; //Esto sustituirá a ps
        stmt = con.createStatement(); //Usamos create... no prepare...
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sentencia);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String codigo = rs.getString(1); //Si codigo es del tipo numérico en la BD debes usar getInt
            String ubicacion = rs.getString(2);
            Producto prod = new Producto(codigo, ubicacion);
            listaProductos.add(prod);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DATMaterial.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

    } finally {
        try {rs.close();  } catch (Exception e) {Logger.getLogger(DATMaterial.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);}
        try {stmt.close();} catch (Exception e) {Logger.getLogger(DATMaterial.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);}
        try {con.close(); } catch (Exception e) {Logger.getLogger(DATMaterial.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);}
    }
    return listaProductos;
}
```

**Notas:**

1. He separado el cierre de recursos en tu bloque  `finally`, ya que conviene tratarlos por separado ([ver esta entrada al respecto](https://www.selikoff.net/2008/07/30/finally-closing-jdbc-resources/)).
2. Si estás usando JDK 7+, conviene que estudies la posibilidad de implementar la nueva funcionalidad llamada **[Try-with-resources](https://blogs.oracle.com/weblogicserver/using-try-with-resources-with-jdbc-objects)**
3. El código propuesto debería funcionar, a no ser que haya otro tipo de problemas, como por ejemplo, que la conexión no se esté creando, que la consulta no arroje datos, etc.

Comment: Gracias por los consejos pero el problema es que en mi base de datos, en la tabla producto guardo solo el id_ubicacion, mas no el nombre de la ubicacion y lo que yo quiero hacer es una consulta SQL de este tipo
SELECT c.campo1, p.campo2 FROM  tabla1 c, tabla2 p WHERE c.campo = p.campo
que es una consulta entre dos tablas diferentes, espero me entiendas.

Comment: @RoberthTorres para unir dos tablas tendrías que hacer: `SELECT t1.campo1, t1.campo2, t2.campo3, t2.campo4 FROM tabla1 t1 INNER JOIN tabla2 t2 ON t1.campoid_tabla1=t2.campoid_tabla2`.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede hacer de esta manera:

```
final String SQL= "SELECT Codigo, Ubicacion FROM producto WHERE p.Codigo=:codigo";
NamedParameterStatement p = new NamedParameterStatement(con, SQL);
p.setInt("codigo", 1);
ResultSet rs=p.executeQuery();
```