# ¿Como puedo obtener los datos de una tabla de una base de datos y almacenarlos en variables? (Java)

Tags: java, base-de-datos, netbeans

Amigos necesito obtener los informacion de los campos de una base datos y almacenarlos en variables para posteriormente manipularlas, eh estado buscando en internet y encontre la siguiente sentencia:

```
ResultSet resultado = (ResultSet) sentencia.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `datos` ");
```

Pero resulta que me da el siguiente error "Cannot find symbol symbol:sentencia"

He visto que comentan en foros que esto les ha funcionado pero no entiendo porque a mi no, ¿Alguien podria ayudarme? ó bien mencionarme otro metodo con el cual pueda conseguir el objetivo...
¡Gracias!

Comment: Y sentencia es que tipo de objeto?

Comment: [Revisa el punto 3 de esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/129394/29967) donde se indica una forma de leer los datos obtenidos una vez la consulta se haya ejecutado.

Comment: ¡Eso si es una buena respuesta!, muy util, gracias...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen varias formas de traer la información de una tabla variando en pequeñas cosas. Te pongo un breve ejemplo con la estructura básica para realizar una consulta a la BD y pasar los datos a variables

```
public void getDatos() {

//creamos las variables que se van a utilizar teniendo en cuenta su dato primitivo (String, int, float, etc...)
String var1;
int var2;
float var3;

//encerramos el bloque del codigo en un try/catch para manejar las excepciones
try {
    // Realizamos la conexion a la BD mediante un método especifico para ello.
    Conectar();

    //Creamos el Statement y el ResulSet necesarios para leer y guardar la informacion de la tabla
    Statement stm = conn.createStatement(); //donde "conn" es una variable del tipo "Connection".
    ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM DATOS");

    //Toda la información está contenida en el ResulSet, ahora procedemos a pasar la info a el ArrayList
    // nos ubicamos en la primera posición del ResultSet
    rs.first();

    var1 = rs.getString(1); //primer dato (observa los datos primitivos)
    var2 = rs.getInt(2); //segundo dato
    var3 = rs.getFloat(3); //tercer dato

    //manejamos la excepcion del tipo "SQLException"
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex);

    } finally {

    //cerramos la conexión a la BD
    Desconectar();
    }
}
```

No te recomiendo realizar las consultas de tipo "SELECT *" a la base de datos ya que resulta algo desordenada y costosa en término de recursos para la BD... siempre has referencia a los nombres de las columnas de la tabla.